# A good way to deal with date and time spans?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, database-design, data-modeling

For my web app i need to handle access requests. Requests are entered for a monday-sunday schedule specifying hours for each day. This week schedule can repeat up to 52 times. A user can have multiple schedules during a week (mon 8-9 and mon 10-11) There are the following requirements:

1. Searchable/filterable
2. Detect overlapping requests

I want the database to handle as much of the lifting as possible. Right now the only design I can think of is storing each day's access as a separate record. Doing this I would pull all accesses for a user and loop to determine if the new request overlaps. This requires code or a stored procedure.

Does anyone have a better database model idea or a clean way to deal with overlaps in code?

Comment: "Records" of single days is very primitive, not Normalised.  What about recurring events, and the 52 weeks ?  What about recurring events (no one is going to be happy about manually repeated entires), and the 52 weeks ?  What about bookings that cross a day boundary (23:00 to 01:00) ? that cross a week boundary ?  You really have to do some work yourself first.  It is not reasonable to expect people to provide a full Data Model for this.  Yes, I have a full DM, working in Production, but no, it is commercial.

Comment: I don't want a full data model. I'm not a DBA and I want a step in the right direction. Short of serializing the data, I don't have an idea right now on how exactly to normalize. The granularity only needs to be to the minute, but all of the things you mentioned are very good questions. Thanks, I'll be thinking about it

Comment: Ok.  I do not use Colin's method (BETWEEN, etc will cause a worktable and be slow), but I can assure you there is no problem for SQL code or performance, using a Normalised (zero duplication) table that stores MeetingStartTime and MeetingDuration.  Ie. The "spans" are not stored; just one row per actual meeting; the empty or conflicted blocks can be identified easily.  The "spans" and recurring events are projections.

Comment: How are you recording how many times a meeting repeats and at which interval? Can a meeting repeat yearly/monthly/bi-monthly/weekly/bi-weekly/daily? And can that repeat interval be mixed? For my application it is currently a weekly only interval, but I was curious how one might deal with varying interval rates aside from adding a column per every possibly interval and projecting from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store each access request in a table with fields with start_time and end_time, then you could use the database's BETWEEN functionality to determine if a particular access would overlap with one already in the database.

As an example, let's say that someone had completed an access request for Monday from 9:00AM to 12:00PM.

Then someone else comes and tries to make an access request for Monday from 11:00AM to 3:00PM.  To determine if this would conflict with something else, you'd need to look for the following possible conditions:

- start_time < Monday 11:00AM && end_time > Monday 11:00AM
- start_time BETWEEN Monday 11:00AM & Monday 3:00PM
- start_time == Monday 11:00AM || end_time == Monday 3:00PM

These can bet translated down to a SQL query which would prevent having to load and iterate over records in the application.  As a bonus, you can use transactions to guard against race conditions.

Comment: When they enter a request they enter times for every day of the week. Your solution seems aimed more at a single day of access. See what I mean about having a procedure because in one request you have up to 7 days? Would you change your approach?

Comment: In the same manner, you could also create a SQL query that verified all seven days at once using AND keywords in your WHERE clause.  If you need to verify each day individually, then I'm not sure - you might either do seven database lookups or find a way to return a result set from the database that had YES/NO values for each day in your query.